# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration. facebook login flask

Tags: python, facebook, flask, facebook-login

I'm trying to add facebook login to my python site. I'm using flask, and did everything like in python facebook-sdk example:
https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/tree/master/examples/flask

But, when I try to use 'Sign In' button, to test it, I get this error:

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

I suppose, that problem is in application settings (I use only website platform with site url : http://localhost:5000/ and same app domain in my application). Can anyone help to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the site url and app domain exactly match the URL where your app exists?

Comment: yes, I run it on my localhost, on port 5000

Comment: What URL do you use - localhost:5000 or 127.0.0.1:5000 ?

Comment: I use http://localhost:5000/ 
When I tried to use 127.0.0.1 - facebook said that it is facebook id :)

Comment: I ran in to this problem initially and had to ensure I used localhost:5000 in my app and in the facebook settings. Mixing 127.0.0.1 and localhost did not work.

Comment: Once again, I don't use 127.0.0.1

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on a localhost:8000 app that's been working forever, and just stopped working in the past couple days with that error message.  I haven't changed any app settings recently, so it appears to be a Facebook issue.

Comment: I created a new test app, i.e. a sub-app of my production app, and it's working for this one. Go figure. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps ... and for my settings, I have "localhost" in App Domains, and "http://localhost:8000/" for Website/Site URL.